# Jackson overcoming underscores in favor of camel-case

Tags: java, jackson

I retrieve a JSON string from internet; like most JSON I've seen it includes long keys that are separated by underscores. Essentially, my goal is to deserialize JSON into java-objects, but I don't use underscores in java-code.

For instance, I might have a `User` class with `firstName` field in camel-case, simultaneously I  need somehow to  tell Jackson to map `first_name` key from JSON to `firstName` class field. Is it possible?

```
class User{
    protected String firstName;
    protected String getFirstName(){return firstName;}
}
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You should use the `@JsonProperty` on the field you want to change the default name mapping.

```
class User{
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    protected String firstName;
    protected String getFirstName(){return firstName;}
}
```

For more info: the [API](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonProperty.html)

Comment: Don't do this, or else you'll have to do it for every property.  See thehpi's response below.

Comment: I was able to only annotate one property, but it did change the order of properties in the generated string: annotated properties showed up last. (Jackson 2.3.0)

Comment: @RyanShillington - Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is your only option if the JSON string you are parsing from does not use a consistent format, i.e., uses both camelCase and underscore?

Comment: @DavidR That is correct. I'm assuming you can't fix the source data?  That sucks.

Comment: @PaulTsai ok, so feel free to use them :)

Comment: Using `propertyNamingStrategy` is a much better way than annotating each property.

Answer (score 476):

In Jackson 2.12+, you can configure the `ObjectMapper` to convert camel case to names with an underscore:

```
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.SNAKE_CASE);
```

Or annotate a specific model class with this annotation:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class;)
```

Before Jackson 2.7, the constant was named:

```
PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES
```

Comment: Note that this was only introduced in Jackson 1.9.

Comment: @deprecated Since 2.7 use SNAKE_CASE instead;

Comment: one qq: when i use snake_case naming strategy will the json files with underscores be deserialized to camel case?

Comment: @Ramswaroop Yes, this makes Jackson both speak and expect snake_case

Comment: @DrewStephens But I couldn't get this behaviour, I had to explicitly add `@JsonProperty("some_property")` to my camel case java variable to properly deserialise.

Comment: @Ramswaroop For me with Jackson 2.7.3 and properties annotated with just `@JsonProperty` (name inferred from normal `camelCase` Java properties) `PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE` made deserialization stop working with camelCase JSON (as I had been using) and require snake_case.

Comment: @DrewStephens Just so that we are on the same page, this is the question which I am referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809959/deserialising-json-with-underscores-to-camel-case-in-java-using-jackson. I had an assumption in mind that using `PropertyNamingStrategy` as `SNAKE_CASE` will make it work both ways instead of requiring me to use `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: @RamPatra naming strategy does work both ways, reading and writing. There is nothing in javadocs (`PropertyNamingStrategy`, `@JsonNaming`) that claims it to only work for serialization, and there are unit tests to verify it also works for reading. You only should use `@JsonProperty` for overriding naming of individual properties.

Comment: Not working for me.  Using Spring Boot 2.1.5.  Will update comment once I figure out why.

Comment: Since Jackson 2.12 it's `PropertyNamingStrategies.SNAKE_CASE`

Comment: When using an annotation with Jackson 2.12+: `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)`

Comment: I see Jackson as a not very consistent library, always changing their constants back and forth.

Answer (score 141):

If its a spring boot application, In application.properties file, just use

> spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE

Or Annotate the model class with this annotation.

> @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)

Comment: If i annotate my class with the "@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)" it works. But if i use "spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE" in "application.properties" it won't. I'm using "Spring Boot (v2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)". Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: same here, `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE` doesn't work, I'm using Spring Boot 2.0

Comment: same here, spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE doesn't work, I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.5. But using annotation is working for me

Comment: Maybe your `ObjectMapper` is not created by Spring? Create a @Configuration class with a @Bean method that returns an ObjectMapper. Not sure if this is necessary.

Comment: I am using Spring boot 2.4.1 and ```spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE``` works for me

Answer (score 60):

If you want this for a Single Class, you can use the [PropertyNamingStrategies](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.html) with the [@JsonNaming](http://www.lookatsrc.com/source/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonNaming.java?a=com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind), annotation, like this:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public static class Request {

    String businessName;
    String businessLegalName;

}
```

Will serialize to:

```
{
    "business_name" : "",
    "business_legal_name" : ""
}
```

Before `Jackson 2.7`, use `PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class`:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
public static class Request {

    String businessName;
    String businessLegalName;

}
```

From `Jackson 2.7` to `Jackson 2.12` the `LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy` is deprecated in favor of `SnakeCaseStrategy`, so you should use:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public static class Request {

    String businessName;
    String businessLegalName;

}
```

Since `Jackson 2.12` the `PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy` is deprecated in favor of `PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy`, you should use:

```java
    @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
    public static class Request {

        String businessName;
        String businessLegalName;

    }
```

Comment: Since `Jackson 2.12` use `PropertyNamingStrategies.LowerCaseStrategy` instead. (Note change from `PropertyNamingStrategy` to `PropertyNamingStrategies`): https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategies.LowerCaseStrategy.html

Answer (score 31):

The above answers regarding `@JsonProperty` and `CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` are 100% accurate, although some people (like me) might be trying to do this inside a Spring MVC application with code-based configuration. Here's sample code (that I have inside `Beans.java`) to achieve the desired effect:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(
            PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
}
```

Comment: An alternative for Spring Boot, if you're using Spring Boot <=1.3, in `application.properties` add `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCOR‌​ES`. For Spring Boot 1.4 use `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE` instead.

Comment: @zapl yes you're right, I probably mentioned jackson's version instead of spring-boot's version. Let me delete that comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: As of version 2.7 of Jackson it is SNAKE_CASE. This worked for me:         `final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(
                PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);`

Answer (score 19):

The current best practice is to configure Jackson within the `application.yml` (or `properties`) file.

Example:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
```

If you have more complex configuration requirements, you can also configure Jackson programmatically.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
        // insert other configurations
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know if you have another instance of jackson2objectmapper being loaded and overriding this one? And can you confirm that even this bean is being loaded?

Comment: Also give DuffJ’s solution a whirl. It’s pretty similar.

Comment: I think tweaking the properties is the right way; and recommended, too. That does the same as this.

Comment: @WesternGun good call. I tend to do this via yaml/properties when possible.

Answer (score 13):

In order to annotate the model class use:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
```

Instead of:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
```

It was deprecated since 2.12.

Answer (score 6):

There are few answers here indicating both strategies for 2 different versions of Jackson library below:

**For Jackson 2.6.***

```
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory()); // or YAMLFactory()
objMapper.setNamingStrategy(
     PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

**For Jackson 2.7.***

```
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory()); // or YAMLFactory()
objMapper.setNamingStrategy(
     PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

Comment: again they deprecated some values, now they have KEBAB_CASE , yum!

Comment: FTR: kebab-case is not snake_case ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Annotating all model classes looks to me as an overkill and Kenny's answer didn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/43271115/4437153. The result of serialization was still camel case.

I realised that there is a problem with my spring configuration, so I had to tackle that problem from another side. Hopefully someone finds it useful, but if I'm doing something against springs' rules then please let me know.

**Solution for Spring MVC 5.2.5 and Jackson 2.11.2**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);           

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        converters.add(converter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the @JsonProperty annotation on the fields of our class to map the fields to the exact names in our JSON

   > ```
   > @JsonProperty("my_name")
   > private String myName;
   > ```
2. You can use @JsonNaming annotation on the class, and all fields will be deserialized using snake case

   > ```
   > @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class) 
   > public class MyClassWithSnakeStrategy { ...
   > ```

}

3. You can use the setPropertyNamingStrategy method on ObjectMapper to configure it for all serialization

   > ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
   > .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);

Answer (score 0):

`PropertyNamingStrategy` should be replaced with `PropertyNamingStrategies` for @JsonNaming