# Underscore issue with JSON - POJO wrt Jersey Webservice

Tags: java, json, web-services

I have a POJO class.

```
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public class Sample implements Serializable {



            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private int local_id;
            private int serverid;

        @JsonProperty("local_id")
            public int getLocalId() {
                return local_id;
            }

            public void setLocalId(int local_id) {
                this.local_id = local_id;
            }

        @JsonProperty("serverid")
             public int getServerId() {
              return serverid;
        }

            public void setServerId(int serverid) {
            this.serverid= serverid;
        }
}
```

Request JSON: { "local_id": 1 , "serverid":0 }

While creating the response JSON for the web service , the tags automatically changes from local_id to localId and serverid to serverId.

Response JSON: { "localId ": 1 , "serverId":0 }

Is there any limitation with underscore and are all tag strings change to camelcase tags ?

Comment: What does your web service look like?

Comment: @chiranjib Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519265/jackson-overcoming-underscores-in-favor-of-camel-case