# Json deserialization/serialization without changing naming in one way

Tags: json, spring, serialization, kotlin, jackson

I have been wondering if there is a possibility to automatically deserialize json to specific object properties, and serialize it with different names without implementing any custom deserializer. I am working on integrating my app with Github API and their naming convention is something I would like to remodel. Once requesting resources I get something like:

```
{
 full_name: "...",
 description: null,
 clone_url: "...",
 stargazers_count: 0,
 created_at: "2018-06-05"
}
```

but I would like to expose them on my side as:

```
{
  fullName: "...",
  description: null,
  cloneUrl: "...",
  stars: 0,
  createdAt: "2018-06-05"
}
```

Here is how my model looks like right now:

```
internal data class GithubRepositoryResponse(@JsonProperty("full_name") val fullName: String,
                                             val description: String?,
                                             @JsonProperty("clone_url") val cloneUrl: URL,
                                             @JsonProperty("stargazers_count") val stars: Int,
                                             @JsonProperty("created_at") val createdAt: LocalDate)
```

Using `@JsonProperty` with value is bidirectional so I get the same property names as declared in annotation which is something I would really like to avoid. Is there any convenient way of dealing with such a scenerio?

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40730352/1532460

Comment: @soon that way I won't be able to keep stargazers_count as stars, I got specification which I have to fulfill so it is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Annotating data class properties with `@JsonAlias` did the trick.