# How to get RequestBody whose attribute are in camelCase but I have application level property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, camelcasing, snakecasing

I have a nested object e.g

```
{   
"driverNumber": 1,
"expressCustomerNumber": 34637593,
"salutationCode": "1",
"firstName": "firstName",
"lastName": "lastName",
"birthday": "1971-04-09T00:00Z",
"placeOfBirth": "",
"birthCountryCode": "",
"address": {
    "isoCountryCode": "US",
    "state": "TX",
    "postCode": "77363",
    "city": "city",
    "street": "street"
    }
}
```

and since my application level property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE so it accepts driver_number(not driverNumber), I can add JsonProperty annotation at each attribute but I don't want to do that. Any other way to read the object.

Comment: please refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519265/jackson-overcoming-underscores-in-favor-of-camel-case

Comment: I had resolved it by specifying PropertyNamingStrategy in ObjectMapper.