# RestTemplate exchange, values are not mapped for a field with underscore

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, objectmapper

To consume  a rest service, this is the service response

```
{
   "message": "200",
   "result": "SUCCESS",
   "Test_Id": "23324"
}
```

Code to consume the service.

```
ResponseEntity<InfoDto> result = null;
final String uri ="https://app.ed.im/api";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, InfoDto.class);
```

This is the dto

```
public class InfoDto implements Serializable {
    private String message;
    private String result;
    private String Test_Id;
}
```

Once this is executed

I had received the values of **message** and **result**, but **Test_Id** value is not mapped.

Comment: Try adding `@JsonProperty("Test_Id")` before Test_Id

Comment: Worked. Why it doesn't match the element name even though its same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an issue with parameter name's code convention, add JsonProperty with exact match

```
@JsonProperty("Test_Id")
private String Test_Id; // prefer rename to testId
```

There's probably an [underscore to camel-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519265/jackson-overcoming-underscores-in-favor-of-camel-case) conversion

Comment: My java model objects are auto-generated and I can't change them to @JsonProperty, they are all annotated with @SerializedName(SERIALIZED_NAME. How can I do this?

Comment: @Devi please ask a new question with more details